# Trying to display data shown depending on what users click

Tags: javascript, php, html

Have a look here: 
http://test.neworgan.org/100/

Scroll down to the community section.

What I'm trying to achieve is to get the data for new organizers, (e.g.: number of friends / amount donated) to show once users click on their thumbnails. right now each user has his or her own unique data stored externally.

Once the users click the thumbnail, 'inline1' appears with the content.

As of now, I'm only able to get the data from the last user to show regardless of whichever user's thumbnails I'm clicking on. I just need a bit of help as to how to change the content depending on which thumbnail users click. So I was wondering if I could have some help here?

Here's that part of the code that matters:

```
      <div class="top-fundraisers-wrapper">
     <div class="subsection top-fundraisers">

    <?php if ($top_fundraisers && is_array($top_fundraisers)): ?>
        <?php foreach ($top_fundraisers as $index => $fundraiser): ?>
           <a title="" class="fancybox" href="#inline1">
        <div class="top-fundraiser">

<div id="newo<?php print htmlentities($index + 1); ?>" class="top-fundraiser-image">
              <img src="<?php
          if($fundraiser['member_pic_medium']) {
                  print htmlentities($fundraiser['member_pic_medium']);
          } else {
            print $template_dir . '/images/portrait_placeholder.png';
          }
              ?>"/>
            </div>
    </div>
    </a>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    <?php endif; ?>

  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="inline1">
    <div class="top-fundraiser-image2">
    <img src="<?php
          if($fundraiser['member_pic_large']) { print htmlentities($fundraiser['member_pic_large']);
          } else {
            print $template_dir . '/images/portrait_placeholder.png';
          }
            ?>"/>
            </div>

    <span class="member-name"><?php print htmlentities($fundraiser['member_name']); ?></span>
        <span class="friend-count"><?php print number_format($fundraiser['num_donors']) . (($fundraiser['num_donors'] == 1) ? ' Friend' : ' Friends'); ?></span>


        <span class="fundraisers-text"> Donated: </span><span class="fundraisers-gold"> $<?php print number_format($fundraiser['total_raised']); ?></span>

</div>
```

Comment: jQuery and PHP don't really mix... your best bet is to provide us the rendered HTML, and the relevant javascript.

Comment: http://test.neworgan.org/100/ here's the link.

the jquery involved for this part is just the fancybox used to display the data/info once users click on the thumbnails

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use Ajax. Something like this

```
$("#button").click( function() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'file.php',
    method: 'post',
    data: { id: $(this).val() },
    error: function() {
        alert('error while requesting...');
    }, success: function(data) {
        alert( data ); /** received data - best to use son **/
    }
 });
 });
```

Next parse json var json = $.parseJSON(data);
or ... use dataJson option.

Next Your data should be inserted using class or id to specific location.

Answer (score 0):

Create another loop for content

```
<?php if ($top_fundraisers && is_array($top_fundraisers)):
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($top_fundraisers as $index => $fundraiser): ?>
        <a title="" class="fancybox" href="#inline<?php echo $i; ?>">
        // ... content
    <?php $i++;
    endforeach;
endif; ?>
```

And another loop

```
<?php if ($top_fundraisers && is_array($top_fundraisers)):
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($top_fundraisers as $index => $fundraiser): ?>
        <div id="inline<?php echo $i; ?>">
            // inline content here
        </div>
    <?php $i++;
    endforeach;
endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope your JavaScript function to open fancybox works fine via calling class. So by following code you do not need to play with Javascript code.

Building anchors tags:

```
<?php
if (!empty($top_fundraisers) && is_array($top_fundraisers)) {
    foreach ($top_fundraisers as $index => $fundraiser) {
        <a title="" class="fancybox" href="#inline<?php echo $fundraiser['id']; ?>">HTML Content Goes Here</a>
        <?php
    } //end of foreach
} // end of if condition
?>
```

Building Popup HTML DOMs:

```
<?php
if (!empty($top_fundraisers) && is_array($top_fundraisers)) {
    foreach ($top_fundraisers as $index => $fundraiser) {
         <div id="inline<?php echo $fundraiser['id']; ?>">HTML Content Goes Here</div>
        <?php
    } //end of foreach
} // end of if condition
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot perform this because PHP runs server-side and JavaScript runs in the browser.

To perform this you can use [`AJAX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) to get the `div` as required by user.

...or store the data client-side and change the content of `#inline1` based on which item was clicked

Comment: ...or store the data client-side and change the content of `#inline1` based on which item was clicked.

Comment: @ahren yeah thats what i thought too. i'm no pro here but all i could think of to solve this was to do a div class change whenever the user clicks a thumbnail. i'm sure this is obviously not the right way.

Comment: @jhonraymos hmmm i think you misunderstood my question a little? i mean i did get some part of the data to show. like you see on the website i shown. just that its not the right data. i just need a little tweaking i think. 

right now i can only seem to pull data from the last user. (last thumbnail). but i need to pull unique data from each one....